# Can Xcode infer an UIImageView's size from an image in a storyboard?

Tags: xcode

(I'm aware of how this is done in code)

When you plop an Image View into a storyboard, and then assign an image to it, is there some convenient way to resize that Image View to the size of the image? So far I've just been keying in dimensions manually, and it feels like I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Just press command and = buttons.

Comment: I see, thanks! Just as a note for anybody else who comes this way, that shortcut activates "size to fit content" under the Editor menu.